# Ошибка в java апплете java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, log4j

Разрабатываю JAVA апплет для подписания документов с помощью смарткарты, на серверной части находится код запуска апплета

```
 echo "<Applet Code=\"Main.class\" 
        name = \"eParakstitajs\"
        mayscript=\"true\"
        codebase = \"".SERVER_FULL_URL."/EDOC2.4.0._22.05\"
        archive = \"
        classesEDOC2.4.jar,
        log4j-1.2.17.jar,
        eparaksts-bc-1.43.0.jar, 
        eparaksts-client-2.4.0.jar, 
        eparaksts-lib-2.4.0.jar, 
        org.apache.commons.codec_1.3.0.v201101211617.jar, 
        pkcs11wrapper-1.2.18.jar,
        plugin.jar, 
        signing-applet-2.4.0.jar, 
        slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, 
        slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar, 

        xmlsec-2.0.2.jar, 

        ./config/\"  
        width=1 
        Height=1
          >
    <PARAM NAME=\"key\"         VALUE=\"{$signKey}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"URL\"         VALUE=\"".SERVER_FULL_URL."\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"PIN1\"        VALUE=\"{$_SESSION["userdata"]["PIN1"]}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"PIN2\"        VALUE=\"{$_SESSION["userdata"]["PIN2"]}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"USERID\"      VALUE=\"{$user[0]["id_lietotajs"]}\">
</Applet>";
```

в указаной директории находятся все перечисленные библиотеки, а так же в Eclipse всё это тоже добавлено в Buildpath, но во время запуска Jav'ы, во время создания объекта

```
 QualifiedSignatureHelper helper = new QualifiedSignatureHelper(
                            signCertificate, ts);
```

появляется исключение

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at lv.eparaksts.helpers.QualifiedSignatureHelper.<clinit>(QualifiedSignatureHelper.java:26)
    at CreateNewSignTimestampedAction.CreateNewSignTimestamped(CreateNewSignTimestampedAction.java:134)
    at Main.init(Main.java:227)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Ну проблемы с класспафом, туда не включена библиотека log4j

Comment: а что представляет из себя classpath в контексте java апплетов?

Comment: посмотрите здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669617/adding-a-third-party-library-to-java-applet и здесь https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html